# Graphing Polar Functions with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath, polar-coordinates

Is it possible to graph a polar function with UIBezierPath?  More than just circles, I'm talking about cardioids, limacons, lemniscates, etc.  Basically I have a single UIView, and want to draw the shape in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no built in methods for shapes like that, but you can always approximate them with a series of very short straight lines. I've had reason to approximate a circle this way, and a circle with ~100 straight lines looks identical to a circle drawn with ovalInRect. It was easiest when doing this, to create the points in polar coordinates first, then convert those in a loop to rectangular coordinates before passing the points array to a method where I add the lines to a bezier path.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my swift helper function (fully commented) that generates the (x,y) coordinates in a given CGRect from a polar coordinate function.

```
func cartesianCoordsForPolarFunc(frame: CGRect, thetaCoefficient:Double, thetaCoefficientDenominator:Double, cosScalar:Double, iPrecision:Double) -> Array<CGPoint> {

    // Frame: The frame in which to fit this curve.
    // thetaCoefficient: The number to scale theta by in the cos.
    // thetaCoefficientDenominator: The denominator of the thetaCoefficient
    // cosScalar: The number to multiply the cos by.
    // iPrecision: The step for continuity. 0 < iPrecision <= 2.pi. Defaults to 0.1

    // Clean inputs
    var precision:Double = 0.1 // Default precision
    if iPrecision != 0 {// Can't be 0.
        precision = iPrecision
    }

    // This is ther polar function
    // var theta: Double = 0 //  0 <= theta <= 2pi
    // let r = cosScalar * cos(thetaCoefficient * theta)

    var points:Array<CGPoint> = [] // We store the points here
    for theta in stride(from: 0, to: 2*Double.pi * thetaCoefficientDenominator, by: precision) { // Try to recreate continuity
        let x = cosScalar * cos(thetaCoefficient * theta) * cos(theta) // Convert to cartesian
        let y = cosScalar * cos(thetaCoefficient * theta) * sin(theta) // Convert to cartesian

        let scaled_x = (Double(frame.width) - 0)/(cosScalar*2)*(x-cosScalar)+Double(frame.width) // Scale to the frame
        let scaled_y = (Double(frame.height) - 0)/(cosScalar*2)*(y-cosScalar)+Double(frame.height) // Scale to the frame

        points.append(CGPoint(x: scaled_x, y:scaled_y)) // Add the result
    }

    return points
}
```

Given those points here's an example of how you would draw a `UIBezierPath`. In my example, this is in a custom UIView function I would call UIPolarCurveView.

```
let flowerPath = UIBezierPath() // Declare my path

// Custom Polar scalars
let k: Double = 9/4
let length = 50

// Draw path
let points = cartesianCoordsForPolarFunc(frame: frame, thetaCoefficient: k, thetaCoefficientDenominator:4 cosScalar: length, iPrecision: 0.01)      flowerPath.move(to: points[0])
for i in 2...points.count {         
       flowerPath.addLine(to: points[i-1])
}

flowerPath.close()
```

Here's the result:
[image: Graph of the polar curve given in the example]
PS: If you plan on having multiple graphs in the same frame, make sure to modify the scaling addition by making the second `cosScalar` the largest of the `cosScalars` used.You can do this by adding an argument to the function in the example.